# Looping thru .JSON dictionary and inserting items via SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, for-loop, sqlite

I am trying to iterate through a .json list. I want to create separate entries in SQLite3 for each of these three sub-lists in 'data'.

```
data = {u'symbols':[{u'optionType': None, u'dividendDate': u'2017-12-29T00:00:00.000000-05:00', u'eps': 2.79, u'currency': u'CAD', u'prevDayClosePrice': 32.41, u'averageVol3Months': 579272, u'industrySubgroup': u'InsuranceLife', u'isTradable': True, u'hasOptions': True, u'optionDurationType': None, u'optionExpiryDate': None, u'symbolId': 32304, u'outstandingShares': 415289000, u'tradeUnit': 1, u'optionStrikePrice': None, u'pe': 11.62, u'lowPrice52': 28.4, u'industrySector': u'FinancialServices', u'optionRoot': u'', u'description': u'POWER CORP OF CDA SV', u'symbol': u'POW.TO', u'securityType': u'Stock', u'dividend': 0.3585, u'minTicks': [{u'pivot': 0, u'minTick': 0.005}, {u'pivot': 0.5, u'minTick': 0.01}], u'averageVol20Days': 506545, u'industryGroup': u'InsuranceLife', u'optionContractDeliverables': {u'cashInLieu': 0, u'underlyings': []}, u'highPrice52': 33.69, u'yield': 4.43, u'listingExchange': u'TSX', u'isQuotable': True, u'optionExerciseType': None, u'marketCap': 13459516489, u'exDate': u'2017-12-07T00:00:00.000000-05:00'}, 

{u'optionType': None, u'dividendDate': u'2018-02-01T00:00:00.000000-05:00', u'eps': 2.95, u'currency': u'CAD', u'prevDayClosePrice': 35.28, u'averageVol3Months': 394431, u'industrySubgroup': u'InsuranceLife', u'isTradable': True, u'hasOptions': True, u'optionDurationType': None, u'optionExpiryDate': None, u'symbolId': 32316, u'outstandingShares': 713871000, u'tradeUnit': 1, u'optionStrikePrice': None, u'pe': 11.96, u'lowPrice52': 31.75, u'industrySector': u'FinancialServices', u'optionRoot': u'', u'description': u'POWER FINANCIAL CP', u'symbol': u'PWF.TO', u'securityType': u'Stock', u'dividend': 0.4125, u'minTicks': [{u'pivot': 0, u'minTick': 0.005}, {u'pivot': 0.5, u'minTick': 0.01}], u'averageVol20Days': 396594, u'industryGroup': u'InsuranceLife', u'optionContractDeliverables': {u'cashInLieu': 0, u'underlyings': []}, u'highPrice52': 37, u'yield': 4.68, u'listingExchange': u'TSX', u'isQuotable': True, u'optionExerciseType': None, u'marketCap': 25185368880, u'exDate': u'2017-12-28T00:00:00.000000-05:00'}, 

{u'optionType': None, u'dividendDate': u'2017-12-07T00:00:00.000000-05:00', u'eps': 2.03, u'currency': u'CAD', u'prevDayClosePrice': 24.85, u'averageVol3Months': 589611, u'industrySubgroup': u'REITRetail', u'isTradable': True, u'hasOptions': True, u'optionDurationType': None, u'optionExpiryDate': None, u'symbolId': 34330, u'outstandingShares': 326529000, u'tradeUnit': 1, u'optionStrikePrice': None, u'pe': 12.25, u'lowPrice52': 23.46, u'industrySector': u'RealEstate', u'optionRoot': u'', u'description': u'RIOCAN REAL EST INV TR', u'symbol': u'REI.UN.TO', u'securityType': u'Stock', u'dividend': 0.1175, u'minTicks': [{u'pivot': 0, u'minTick': 0.005}, {u'pivot': 0.5, u'minTick': 0.01}], u'averageVol20Days': 575707, u'industryGroup': u'REITs', u'optionContractDeliverables': {u'cashInLieu': 0, u'underlyings': []}, u'highPrice52': 27.25, u'yield': 5.68, u'listingExchange': u'TSX', u'isQuotable': True, u'optionExerciseType': None, u'marketCap': 8114245650, u'exDate': u'2017-11-29T00:00:00.000000-05:00'}]}
```

This is part of the code I have (I think the problem is due a misunderstanding on how the for loop interacts with the son data):

```
indice = -1    

for y in data:

            indice +=1

            data = data['symbols'][indice]
            try:
                conn = sqlite3.connect('sql/investment_databse.db')
                c = conn.cursor()
                with conn:
                    c.execute('''INSERT INTO symbols(symbol,...
```

The code works to insert only the first item in data. I want it to loop through all three.

I thought that if I increase the [indice] by 1 every loop it would cycle through. It seems to me that Python thinks there is only one element in the data to cycle through.

Can you help me understand why my code skips over the second two items and help write a code that will insert all three elements of the data dictionary as separate SQL entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* only one element in `data`; the key `symbols`.

It is `data["symbols"]` you should be iterating over. And you don't need `indice` at all.

```
for symbol in data["symbols"]:
   print(symbol["optionType"]) # etc
```

Comment: It is verking! Thanks so much.